# Corona SDK and IBOutlets

Tags: coronasdk

Somebody correct me if im wrong.

There is no way (at least no supported way) to create a View/Windows based iPhone app using the Corona SDK?

I say this mainly because i see no way to work with IBOutlets (anything related to the interface builder). Which makes me believe Corona is not converting anything to Objective C, but rather converts the Lua script to C/C++.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on everything ive seen and read, it seems Corona SDK is 100% opengl, thus there is no concept of connecting with the device's native UI framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest new feature in Corona (currently available only to subscribers) is Corona UI, which emulates most of the native UI components:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UHNSRilB-0

Note that I say "emulated." It's still not connecting to IBOutlets but it may accomplish what you want.

Comment: The open source version of CoronaUI has been deprecated in favor of the newly integrated "CoronaUI" interface widgets. See this page for more information: http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/widget

It's still a "simulated" solution, so if you need an actual IBOutlet then unfortunately that won't work, however, if you just need similar functionality to native widgets, then this should be perfect for you.

Answer (score 2):

Corona UI supports most of the native UI components, you can also include widget_iOS for other native components of iOS otherwise you can create your own custom objects.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve it using Corona Enterprise edition. It has all the option to bridging between LUA and C/C++, lua and objective-C or LUA AND JAVA.

Corona Enterprise provides feature to work in Xcode- objective-C environment to execute same functionalities in corona apps.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/native/enterprise/index.html

Hope this helps for your question.